# show and hide password using drawable icons in android

Tags: java, android, passwords, icons, drawable

I have designed a screen with password field using EditText, in the EditText I am using drawableRightIcon which has to show the password visible when we click the drawable button and also replace that drawable icon with another icon? can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following statements when your image button is clicked

```
String password= your_editText.getText().toString().trim();
your_editText.setText(password);
your_imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code that I'm using currently in my apps for this purpose. We basically put a touch listener to our `EditText` and identify if the click occurred on the drawable and act accordingly (also switching icons):

```
getPasswordEditText().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2; // index

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (getPasswordEditText().getRight() - getPasswordEditText().getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        if (passwordShown) {
                            passwordShown = false;
                            // 129 is obtained by bitwise ORing InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                            getPasswordEditText().setInputType(129);

                            // Need to call following as the font is changed to mono-space by default for password fields
                            getPasswordEditText().setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
                            getPasswordEditText().setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.locked_icon, 0);
                        } else {
                            passwordShown = true;
                            getPasswordEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

                            getPasswordEditText().setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.unlocked_icon, 0);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: while using this code, first time the icon is changing but password is not visible, if I click again that icon then it is changing, first time is not working ??

Comment: I forgot to mention, initially `password_shown` needs to be false.

Comment: Cool...if you feel like it, you may want to 'accept' this answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to show and hide the password. You can use an `ImageView` beside the check box.

Used a checkbox (you can use a image button also instead of it using the same concept except that you have to use an onCLickListener instead).

```
     loginShowHidePassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // EditText loses the cursor position when you change the InputType
            int curPos = mPasswordView.getSelectionStart();
            if (isChecked) {
                mPasswordView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD); 
   imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);

            } else {
                mPasswordView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
   loginShowHidePassword.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);

            }
            mPasswordView.setSelection(curPos);
        }
    });
```

You need to save a new a new image named newImage in drawable.

`mPasswordView` is the password EditText

Comment: if u dint get it how to use the conditions inside the if braces. Do let me know for onclicklistner()